# How do you say “Grandad Hughie” and “Nana Norma”?

Tags: translation

Can someone translate? “Grandad Hughie” and “Nana Norma” to Chinese for me please, as I do not trust Google Translate to be right.

Comment: Google: "休伊爺爺” “娜娜諾瑪”.  Nana is a pet name for grandmother, so it should be translated as "休伊爺爺" and  "諾瑪奶奶”

Comment: Hughie 爺爺, Norma 祖母, 奶奶,  外祖母, 外婆 or 奶奶, Depends on the region). the former two are your father's mother, the latter two are your mother's mother.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends, not so simple in Chinese:

the father of the husband is 爷爷 yéye
the father of the wife is 外公 wàigōng

the mother of the husband is 奶奶 nǎinai
the mother of the wife is 外婆 wàipó

Hughie gets transliterated as 雨神 yǔshén or 休吉 xiūjí
Norma gets transliterated as 诺尔玛 nuoěrmǎ or just 诺玛 nuomǎ

Talking directly to granma or grandad, just say 爷爷 yéye, 外公 wàigōng, 奶奶 nǎinai, 外婆 wàipó.

Referring to them, put the name first:

雨神 yǔshén 爷爷 yéye,
诺尔玛 nuoěrmǎ 外婆 wàipó

Every relative has a different title in Chinese! I will never remember them all!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationship between you and the person you are addressing:

1. Blood Relatives (Note, the way to address the same type of relative varies with  the geographic regions)

- Your father's father (Grandad): 祖父,爺爺,阿公
- Your father's mother (Nana): 祖母,奶奶,婆婆,阿嬤
- Your mother's father (Grandad): 外祖父,外公,(外家)阿公
- Your mother's mother (Nana): 外祖母,外婆,(外家)阿嬤

2. Typical - Addressing Elders

- Male (x Grandad): X爺爺, x公公, 阿公
- Female (x Nana): x奶奶, x婆婆, 阿嬤

x - Surname. Note, for Chinese, it is unpolite to address the elder by his/her first name.